# How to omit newlines in Python?

Tags: python

I know..... one way to omitting new lines in Python with concatenation:

```
a = 'strin'  
b = 2  
print str(b)+a
```

how many ways we can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes finally I found the answer.
We can omit newlines in 3:

1. **"+"** (Concatenation)
   Ex:

   ```
   a = sachin
   b = 'tendulkar' 
   a += b 
   print(a)
   ```
2. By using **","** (comma) see above answers
3. By using **write() function:**

   ```
   import sys
   write = sys.stdout.write
   write('20)
   write('17')
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   2017
   ```

   The `write()` method does not add a newline character ('\n') to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you are using Python2.x. You can try following:

1. use a trailing comma.

   ```
    print a, # no new line will be printed
   ```
2. use print function from future

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function
   print(a,end='') # no new line will be printed
   ```

And for Python3.x following will do. `Do not need to import print function`

```
     print(a,end='')
```

Comment: Thak you... but buddy i am using 3.5.2,

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also,

`print(repr(b), a) # ',' will avoid the newline`

Comment: `print(a, end="")` will let you decide the character(s) you wish to end the output with.